# Can't upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS with official upgrade instructions

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

The official instructions are found here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade and here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VividUpgrades

I followed the instructions at an earlier date, and proceeded with the installation, but when told "this may take 3 hours, proceed or complete at another time?" I canceled as I did not have necessary time to complete.

At this time I am now unable to proceed with an upgrade using the official upgrade instructions found at the above 3 sources. update-manager does not provide an option to upgrade even after following the instructions.

Edit:

df output:

```
    Filesystem             1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                     1959412         4   1959408   1% /dev
tmpfs                     395572      1360    394212   1% /run
/dev/sda8               19091584   9593272   8505444  54% /
none                           4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                     1977840       592   1977248   1% /run/shm
none                      102400        44    102356   1% /run/user
/dev/sda9                 464808     54852    381438  13% /boot
/dev/sda10              17182104  12796300   3489960  79% /home
/home/neptune/.Private  17182104  12796300   3489960  79% /home/neptune
/dev/sda4              679686516 626563568  53122948  93% /media/neptune
```

output of lsblk -f:

```
    NAME    FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                  
├─sda1               
├─sda2               
├─sda3               
├─sda4               /media/neptune/TI10686900F
├─sda5               
├─sda6               
├─sda7               
├─sda8               /
├─sda9               /boot
└─sda10              /home
```

output of parted -ls:

```
Model: ATA HGST HTS541075A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag
 2      1075MB  1180MB  105MB   fat32        Basic data partition  boot
 3      1180MB  1314MB  134MB   ntfs         Basic data partition  msftres
 4      1314MB  697GB   696GB   ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata
 5      697GB   701GB   3999MB
 8      701GB   721GB   20.0GB  ext4
 9      721GB   722GB   500MB   ext4
10      722GB   740GB   18.0GB  ext4
 6      740GB   740GB   530MB   ntfs                               hidden, diag
 7      740GB   750GB   9803MB  ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag
```

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VividUpgrades this is where it says ubuntu goes from 14.04 to 15.04

Comment: 15.04 is no longer supported, so you can't upgrade to it.  15.10 is also no longer supported.  So, it would be direct to 16.04 LTS.  https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: Terrance, took a look at your link and those are the same instructions I linked to, just at a different URL. Those instructions do not work.

Comment: What version does it say it wants to upgrade to when you run `do-release-upgrade -d` from a terminal window?

Comment: Terrance I'm trying to do that, but my boot partition is only about 450mb in total, and I need 750mb, so I need to go about figuring out how to resizing it to do the upgrade... Sometimes Ubuntu feels hard.. I have to leave for now but will report back tomorrow.. thanks for the help for now

Comment: Which partition is only 450 MB, and what about the other partitions? It would help us help you, if you run the following commands and edit your question to post the output (indent 4 spaces to display it as `code`).  `df` , `sudo lsblk -f`, `sudo parted -ls`

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the help - I edited my comment with the output of those 3 commands. The 450mb partition is the /boot partition. Ubuntu told me "free up more space on /boot, requires 750mb"

Comment: The boot partition `/dev/sda9` is full because of old kernels. If you remove all kernels except the current one, there should be space for the future kernel, that comes with the next release. But this kind of upgrade is risky. *Backup* the current system or at the very least of all files that you don't want to lose. A better alternative is to keep the `/home` partition and make a fresh installation of 16.04.1 LTS. A the installer's partitioning window, select *Something else*, select the existing partitions to be used. *Do not format the `/home` partition*, but format the other partitions.

Comment: Looking a second time at`/dev/sda9` it does not seem full at all, it looks too empty. Maybe your current system is missing some important files in the boot partition. This makes it even more important to backup at the very least of all files that you don't want to lose. I suggest that you  keep the `/home` partition and make a fresh installation of 16.04.1 LTS (as described in the previous comment). Do *not* format `/home`.

Comment: @sudodus well the /boot partition is only 450mb total, and 16.04 says it needs 750mb.

Comment: is /home just a data partition? I could migrate all of my data to my old windows partition and format /home, then use the space for a 16.04 installation

Comment: Which partition do you mean? Which tools says it is  only 450mb total? - No, /home is a system partition, containing your data files, but also 'your' settings for the desktop environment and for many applications programs.

Comment: Hmm, honestly I just browsed there through the system folders to /boot and it says it has 450mb -- but also, when I ran the upgrade the message indicating that the upgrade required 750mb told me boot was only 450mb. What command should I be using to check the size of that partition? Also, is it reasonably straight forward to resize it.... I'm leaning towards backing up my files, formatting over this Ubuntu install and just clean installing ubuntu with 16.04.